# How to prevent git pull request if JSLint fails

Tags: github, gruntjs, jshint

I am working on a large project with a number of other developers.

We have implement JSHint which will throw an error when `grunt build` is run if the JavaScript does not pass the Lint.

I would like to know if it is possible to integrate directly with Github so that a Pull Request will not be allowed to be merged unless it passes in JSHint.

Is there a way or tool to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't prevent pull requests from being merged; however, you can automatically run JSLint using [Travis-CI](https://travis-ci.org/), which will put a big red X on pull requests that do not pass JSLint. Hopefully this is enough to stop people from merging these pull requests.

[This blog post](http://manuel.manuelles.nl/blog/2012/06/22/integrate-travis-ci-into-grunt/) gives a good introduction to running `grunt` tasks on Travis-CI.

Comment: I think you can actually make it so that the PR cannot be merged without a passing build on Travis. [This open PR](https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener/pull/93) has that... Just stumbled upon this as I am researching this myself.

Comment: The green "merge" button isn't there, but nothing stops anyone from doing the merge manually on the command line, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

There is a free way to do it too by [lint-review](https://github.com/markstory/lint-review)

As @tbekolay said, it puts a red sign.

Also, you will see the problems as comments on the code wich is super cool.

But you can merge it manually.

[image]